# how to open popup on click of a marker from the directions service?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**UPDATE**
when i click green marker,it's display address of location.can i change it?

**LATER EDIT :**
is it possible to open popup on click of a marker from the directions service?
or try the other way like only hide a marker from the directions service(green marker) and display only red marker(hide only green marker not it's route)?is it good way?

**if not possible, please suggest some alternative ideas.**

**OLDER:**

i have a two types of marker on google map.the red marker is normal marker which represent location.and green marker is route marker(its represent many of waypoints of the map).
I modify the infowindow with textbox.which is open on click red marker.

actually i am trying to do is, first i place multiple markers on google map then i draw route between this markers.this thing is done.reminder thing is on click green marker one popup is opened in which user enter price and then click the button.then i got this value and store it to database.
the problem is:

(1) how to open same infowindow on click of green marker?
    in short,how to write a code for display infowindow on click of of green marker.
   how to find click event of green marker?

[image]

[image]

`code is:`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var markerarray=new Array(); 
      //for way points
      var waypts=[];
      //array in json format for placing multiple marker
      var locations = <?php echo json_encode($lat1);?>;

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.0171240, 72.5330533),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    <!--  *************  for placing markers  ************  -->

      var marker, i;
      for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
      { 
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][3], locations[i][4]), 
        map: map  //enable if you want marker
      });

      //push value into way points
      waypts.push({
                  location:locations[i][0],
                  stopover:true
      });

      //create array for polyline
      markerarray[i] = marker.getPosition();//(Array(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]));

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            var data='<div style="height:150px !important"><table><tr><td>Enter Price</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="prc" id="prc" /></td></tr></table></div>';
            infowindow.setContent(data);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
        })(marker, i));
      } 


    <!--  **************    for route between markers   *******************  -->

        var first=locations[locations.length-1][0];
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        //directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            polylineOptions: {
              strokeColor: 'red',//"black",
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 3
            }
        });
        var start = locations[0][0];//"Bopal, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India";
        var end = locations[locations.length-1][0];//"Nikol, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India";

        //remove start destination from array
        waypts.shift();

        //remove end destination from array
        waypts.pop();

        var request = {
              origin:start,
              destination:end,
              waypoints:waypts,
              travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  If you want to add an event listener to a marker, you need a reference to it.  The only documented way to get a reference to a marker from the directions service is to create them yourself.

Comment: [Custom Markers added to a route from the directions service, with event handlers (which open an infowindow](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible but it will take some time for code, The way is if you are using for mobile device then you need to accelerator from your device and call geolocation function on position change I think you understand and the second method is from purely javascript method for that you need to call your geolocation function within set Interval understand also draw line separately from marker your marker function only calls within set Intervals for getting your current location with infowindow. Example is :

var map;

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
 //keep this in setInterval
  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}
//close here your set interval
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can hide the default marker such that you can build a custom marker on the clicked location. This code is to hide the marker.

```
var rendererOptions = {
    suppressMarkers : true      
}
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```